# Cyberduck Connection Fails/Timeout

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, sftp, cyberduck

How would I go about changing either my SSH config or Cyberduck configuration to enable SFTP connections from my local machine to connect through a proxy server and then connect to my destination server? Right now, my connection fails/times out in Cyberduck. However, I can reach the server just fine via SFTP from a Terminal window and I figure that something might be wrong with my SSH config.

This is how my SSH config currently looks:

```
Host proxyserveraddress.test.com
ProxyCommand none
# PreferredAuthentications publickey

Host server1.test.com

Host server2.test.com

Host server3.test.com

######## DEFAULTS #########

Host *.test.com
User myusername
Port 8622
PreferredAuthentications publickey,password
ProxyCommand ssh proxyserveraddress.test.com exec nc %h %p 2>/dev/null
```

As a specific example based on this sample config -

How would I, for example, modify this config to have Cyberduck on my local machine connect first to proxyserveraddress.test.com and then to server1.test.com?

Comment: Did you try to connect to the different servers using plain ssh with the `-v` option to see what happens?

Comment: I have no problems connecting to the server via SSH from the Terminal. It is when I try to make a SFTP connection from Cyberduck that the connection attempt fails and times out. Cyberduck doesn't provide any error details.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that cyberduck doesn't use SSH internally but implements the SSH protocol by itself.

From [their wiki page on sftp](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/de/howto/sftp):

> The following configuration options from ~/.ssh/config are supported
>   for SFTP connections:
>
> - *IdentityFile* for public key authentication.
> - *HostName* aliases.
> - *User* preference for login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar config, which works fine for me.

It might help to explicitly exclude the proxy server from the last `Host` block:

```
Host *.test.com !proxyserveradres.test.com
    ProxyCommand ...
```

Besides, you could try the `-W` option (this basically does the same as `nc`, but without the extra command, thus it's more efficient and there's one possible source for errors less)

```
ProxyCommand ssh proxyserveraddress.test.com -W %h:%p
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestions, but still no luck with Cyberduck. The connection still fails/times out.